# consulta parametrizada sql en c# por que no me reconoce el entero?

Tags: c#, sql, visual, studio

Tengo un problema con parametrizar los valores ya que me marca System exception, cuando le paso los valores sin parametrizar en la consulta sql si me realiza el insert, me estara faltando algo ?

**Codigo**

```
// cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Ubicaciones] (NombreUbicacion, Fecha, IDusuario) VALUES ('"+ubicacion+ "','" + fecha + "',"+id+" )", cn);
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Ubicaciones] (NombreUbicacion, Fecha, IDusuario) VALUES  (@ubicacion, @fecha, @idusuario)", cn);
int result  = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//cmd.Prepare();
             
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ubicacion", ubicacion);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);

/*Aqui en esta asignacion es la que no me toma bien la asignacion ya que cuando se 
lo paso directamente sin parametrizar si me permite hacer el insert
*/

cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int); 
cmd.Parameters["@idusuario"].Value = idusuario;
```

Comment: Me queda la duda si tu Id, es autoincremental en la base de datos y por eso te dira error. Porque vos en el sql no pasas ese id y despues con los parametros si queres hacerlo.

Comment: Asi es es autoincrmental pero donde voy a insertar es en otro campo con clave foranea, creo que ya estoy identificando el por que del error me parece que debo usar propiedades get y set para acceder a los valores que obtengo de una consulta sql, si tienen un ejemplo se los agredeceria

Comment: Los parámetros que tienes que pasar son estos tres: `@ubicacion, @fecha, @idusuario` pues son los que has indicado en la consulta. Si el ID es autoincremental no es necesario incluirlo ni en la instrucción SQL ni pasarlo como parámetro, pues el manejador asignará el ID que corresponda según el valor del contador autoincremental. Lo que sí debes es indicar tus tres parámetros y sus valores. El error debe estar ocurriendo por ese motivo.

Comment: Si claro asi tal cual lo mencionas tengo el proceso pero por alguna razon no me permite hacer la inserccion con los valores parametrizados @valor_name, cuando se los paso directamientes de como los recibo "+valor_name_int+ ", '"+valor_name_string+"' , si me lo acepta, revisare lo de los metodos get y set muchas gracias por las sugerencias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude notar dos errores en el código que publicaste:

1. La línea `int result  = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ejecuta la instrucción contra la base de datos y la tienes ubicada antes de asignar los parámetros. Debes ubicarla después de los parámetros.
2. En la línea `cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);`, estás creando el parámetro con el nombre `id`. Debes cambiarlo por `idusuario` que es el nombre que tienes en la instrucción `INSERT`.

El código corregido quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Ubicaciones] (NombreUbicacion, Fecha, IDusuario) VALUES  (@ubicacion, @fecha, @idusuario)", cn))

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ubicacion", ubicacion);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);

    // Corrige el nombre del parámetro
    //                  |         
    //                  V         
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idusuario", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@idusuario"].Value = idusuario;

    // La ejecución del query debe ir después de asignar todos los parámetros
    //               |
    //               V
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! tenias mucha razon ya esta funcionando perfectamente gracias por la ayuda Maestro saludos en hora buena.